# nodejs conflicting with vue native router

Tags: node.js, vue-native

nodejs version 14.17.5
vue native version 0.3.0

I am developing an application that requires navigation in APP.

When i give command "**npm run start**" the application successfully runs.

Package.json dependencies installed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCgQC.png)

For navigation when i run command "**npm install view-native-router**" it shows the error message as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i19dJ.png)

Does anybody have the idea what could possibly have gone wrong? Is it a compatibility issue ?

Comment: Please provide your dependencies list and error message as text in the question and not as images or external links. [See this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is not the first time we have a peer dependency problem here and the last issue was marked as solved.

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/vue-native-router/issues/45

Since you have a higher version of vue-native-core in local, try add `--legacy-peer-deps` to `npm install` to see if works.

Comment: Thank you veryuch for your response,I created new project and installed each package seperatly, I tried the npm install command with -- legacy-peer- deps,, with the ones that shows errors. Issue has resolved . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Though --force or --legacy-peer-deps may work for some but not everyone.

My solution is to start using yarn! Install it by the following:

```
$ npm i -g yarn
```

After its installed, its advised that you delete the project and redo the vue-native-cli init command so it can use yarn from there, but you can also just directly use the following command without deleting the project:

```
$ yarn install vue-native-scripts
```